# Problem with recovery mode

Tags: 18.04, recovery-mode

I'm running Ubuntu 18 and while I load recovery mod it only show numbers running up in increasing order and it didn't stop.

How can I stop this booting and stop running recovery mode?

Comment: Why did you start Recovery Mode? Are you using version 18.04 or 18.10 ? Please click [edit] and put the explanation in the Question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Comment: Tell me EXACTLY how you got to, or how you started, Recovery Mode.